# A good approximation for collision probability between (two) sets of random variables

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, cryptography

We face many places to find the collision probability of two sets (or more) in my case the cryptographic hash functions. We can formalize as;

Given two sets of random variables $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ compromised $m$ and $n$ elements, respectively. Consider $t$ discrete values where each variable  $\{A_1, A_2,\ldots,A_m\}$ and $\{B_1, B_2,\ldots,B_n\}$ can assume any of the $t$ values with equally likely probability.  Clearly, a collision is at least one element of $\mathbf{A}$ is also in $\mathbf{B}$.

The problem investigated in

- 2003, [Collision probability between sets of random variables](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167715203001688) by Michael C. Wendl.

**The probability of no collision** $P_0(m,n,t)$ is given in the below theorem;

- **Theorem 1** (Probability of success). The probability of no collisions between two sets of random variables $\{A_1, A_2,\ldots,A_m\}$ and $\{B_1, B_2,\ldots,B_n\}$, the elements of which can assume any of $t$ discrete values with equally likely probability is $$ P_0(m,n,t) = \frac{1}{t^{m+n}}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n} S_2(m,i)S_2(n,j) \prod_{k=0}^{i+j-1} t-k$$

  where $S_2$ represents [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

When $t$ becomes very large like $2^{64}$ we cannot use this theorem to calculate the probability. Therefore we need a good approximation as in the birthday problem.

Is there any good approximation for this theorem/problem that can be used easily to calculate large values assuming that  $A_1,\dots,A_m,B_1,\dots,B_n$ are **independent and identically distributed random variables each uniformly distributed** over the set $[t]:=\{1,\dots,t\}$.

Comment: What is the definition of a collision between two sets of random variables $\{A_1, A_2,\ldots,A_m\}$ and $\{B_1, B_2,\ldots,B_m\}$? Also, did you mean $B_n$ in place of $B_m$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis thanks for the typo. The usual, if at least one element of $\mathsf{A}$ is in $\mathsf{B}$ it is a collision ($A_i = B_j)$ from some $i$ and $j$...  I.e., the intersection of  $\mathsf{A}$ and $\mathsf{B}$ is not empty. Consider two groups of people, if there is one person on the first group who has the same birthday in the other then we have a collision between these two groups ( however, random people cannot form a set, at least consider that groups of people are forming sets according to their birthdays).

Comment: What are then the $A_i$'s and $B_j$'s? Are they all iid random variables?

Comment: Taken from $t$ discrete values like the days of the year or from $[0,2^{64}-1]$, they are equally likely...

Comment: Can you just answer my questions? I only need formal definitions.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "a collision in at least one element of $\mathbf{A}$ is also in $\mathbf{B}$"? What is "a collision in at least one element of $\mathbf{A}$"? What do you mean by "[the collision] is also in $\mathbf{B}$"?

Comment: @IosifPinelis there the `in` -> is a typo for `is`.  Doesn't the theorem of Wendl clear for the  _equally likely probability_? Consider an element of $\mathsf{A}$ if this is also an element of $\mathsf{B}$ then this is a collision.

Comment: No, unfortunately, Wendl's paper has no clear definition of a collision. Again, are the $A_i$'s and $B_j$'s all together iid random variables?

Comment: @IosifPinelis don't they define it on the second paragraph of the introduction starting from _In many cases_? In my case, you may assume that they are iid random variables.

Comment: No, Wendl does not define the **joint** distribution of $A_1,\dots,A_m,B_1,\dots,B_n$, without which there can be no definite answer.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I see your point, however, I consider that was the case, otherwise the theorem has no good ground, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are assuming that $A_1,\dots,A_m,B_1,\dots,B_n$ are iid random variables each uniformly distributed over the set $[t]:=\{1,\dots,t\}$.

By the [Bonferroni inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality#Bonferroni_inequalities), for the probability of at least one collision
\begin{equation}
    p:=P\Big(\bigcup_{(i,j)\in[m]\times[n]} \{A_i=B_j\}\Big), 
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{equation}
    p_1-p_2\le p\le p_1,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    p_1:=\sum_{(i,j)\in[m]\times[n]} P(A_i=B_j)=\frac{mn}t
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    p_2:=\sum_{
    \substack{(i_1,j_1)\in[m]\times[n], \\ 
    (i_2,j_2)\in[m]\times[n]\setminus\{(i_1,j_1)\}}
    } P(A_{i_1}=B_{j_1},A_{i_2}=B_{j_2})=\frac{mn(mn-1)}{t^2}
    =o\Big(\frac{mn}t\Big)
\end{equation}
if $mn=o(t)$.

So,
\begin{equation}
    p\sim\frac{mn}t
\end{equation}
if $mn=o(t)$.

Thus, the probability of no collisions is
\begin{equation}
    1-p=1-\frac{mn}t\,(1+o(1)) 
\end{equation}
for very large $t$, that is, for $t$ much greater than $mn$.